# Connecting PostgreSQL from TypeORM docker container

Tags: postgresql, typescript, docker, typeorm

I am trying to connect a postgres db to nodejs using typeorm.

I tried doing this with both postgres and nodejs in localhost and it worked fine. However I am having problems when I put postgres and nodejs into docker containers.

(The "IPAdress" field in `docker inspect` for postgres container is 172.19.0.3)

Error from Nodejs:

```
web_1    | error: TypeORM connection error:  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.3:5433
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - "9001:9001"
    links:
      - pg_db

  pg_db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5433:5433"
    env_file: 
      - docker.env
```

ormconfig.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "default",
    "driver": {
      "type": "postgres",
      "host": "pg_db",
      "port": 5433,
      "username": "postgres",
      "password": "test",
      "database": "testDB"
    },
    "autoSchemaSync": true,
    "entities": [
      "src/controller/entity/*.js"
    ],
    "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/controller/entity"
    }
  }
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The default port of PostgreSQL is **5432**. Change it in your nodejs config.

The port exposing is *not* necessary for your nodejs, that is only to link that port to your localhost (or other IPs):

```
    ports:
      - "5433:5433"
```

You can remove them.

But, if you need to postgres listen to 5433 anyway, you will need some customization:

```
  pg_db:
    ...
    environment:
    - PGPORT=5433
    ...
```

Comment: Wow, I'm stupid. Thanks that fixed it.

I intentionally made it 5433 because the localhost instance of postgres was using port 5432 but I for some reason thought the docker container postgres will automatically use 5433.